# How to choose label/target for RNN models?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

When training a character RNN, if we have an input X = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_t), we split it as two parts: X_train = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_(t-1)), y_train = (x_2, x_3, ..., x_t).

Why would we do that? Why not set y_train = (x_(t+1)), i.e. the next character that we want to predict?

I'm trying to predict other time series data with RNN, and it really confuses me how to choose the label/target for the model.

Answer (score 0):

We split the data like this because we want to train our model to predict the next character in the sequence, given the previous characters and the model state. In other words, given a sequence `x`, consisting of `T` inputs, we are training the RNN language model `h` to estimate the following distribution: p(x<sub>t</sub> | x<sub><t</sub>, h).

If we consider the character sequence `stack`, defined as:

> s, t, a, c, k

We also want two special "characters" to denote the start and the end of a word. Let's use `$` to denote the start and `^` to mean the end of a word. Therefore, the entire sequence is now `$, s, t, a, c, k, ^`.

The input sequence x<sub>train</sub> is:

> $, s, t, a, c, k

This sequence contains t=6 timestep inputs to the RNN: x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>, x<sub>5</sub>, x<sub>6</sub>

The target sequence y<sub>train</sub> is simply the input sequence shifted one timestep to the right, i.e. y<sub>t</sub>=x<sub>t-1</sub>.

> s, t, a, c, k, ^